# How to specify dynamic default values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New to C# here... trying to figure out how the below `new GameObject[20, 20]` can actually reference the private property values instead of the hard coded values.

```
private int xRadius = 20;
private int yRadius = 20;

private GameObject [,] grid = new GameObject[20, 20];
```

I've tried variations of `this.xRadius` and `self.xRadius` with no luck.  How can I do this?

Comment: @sixones answer covers a few other possible implementations. Worth reviewing, in my opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `this` in the variable declaration scope of a class because at that moment in time there is no reason for `xRadius` to be defined before `grid`.

You can achieve what you want by either declaring `xRadius` and `yRadius` as constants (constants are immutable variables which don't change during runtime);

```
private const xRadius = 20;
private const yRadius = 20;

private GameObject[,] grid = new GameObject[xRadius, yRadius];
```

Or marking them as static variables (static variables exist outside of any class instance and will available after any class instances disappear);

```
class Example {
    private static xRadius = 20;
    private static yRadius = 20;

    private GameObject[,] grid = new GameObject[Example.xRadius, Example.yRadius];
```

Or you could define the grid in your classes constructor and use a normal class variable reference;

```
class Example {
    public Example() {
        this.grid = new GameObject[this.xRadius, this.yRadius];
    }
}
```

The fastest solution (in terms of less resource usage at runtime) is using `constants` as the values will be copied over at compile time and they wont occupy any extra resources, the most dynamic solution is setting them in the constructor or before you access the grid object this would allow you to change `xRadius` and `yRadius` at runtime and re-initialise the `grid` variable using the same radius variables.

Answer (score 3):

Field initializers are not able to access instance members, because they are run in a static context. Thus, they (like static methods) are unable to reference instance methods.

Assuming the containing class is `Foo`, you can initialize `grid` in the constructor,

```
class Foo
{
    private int xRadius = 20;
    private int yRadius = 20;

    private GameObject[,] grid;

    public Foo()
    {
        grid = new GameObject[xRadius, yRadius];
    }
}
```